# Is there a way to send an in-progress Android app to someone to test?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been developing an Android app in Android Studio. I'd like to be able to send my current app to a friend privately, for feedback purposes.

Is there a function in Android Studio that will let me do this?

Comment: If it is stable, just send the .apk file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a function in Android Studio that will let me do this?

No.

What you can do is (as suggested in the comments) use the debug apk that is also installed to your phone when testing and send that to your friend (via email for example).

It's located in `<project>/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`

Other options are to start an alpha/beta program in the developer section of the play store and invite your friend through there, then he will be invited to join the test program. This requires a developer account that costs $25, as well as a signed apk instead of a debug version.

Emailing him the apk is the easier way, but the alpha/beta programs allow your friend to send you crash reports, should the app crash.

Comment: $25 one-time fee or $25/year?

Comment: @user6261756 it's a one time fee

Comment: One time. Such an account just to share with one person is overkill. But if you want to publish to play store later anyway, you'll need the account. In this case you could also use it for this.

Answer (score 2):

`Android Studio` does not provide any features to distribute apps.

Just generate a signed `APK` file and send it to your friend.

Note: This is the same `APK` you would upload to Google Play if you wanted to publish your app.

Comment: What does it mean to generate a signed APK? Can an "unsigned" APK be sent?

Comment: @user6261756 yes you can send an unsigned apk. It's a file you can send your friend, when he clicks it, he is prompted to install it

Comment: Yes you can also share an unsigned apk. The advantage of a signed apk is that it can be updated from Play store later.

Comment: Also an unsigned apk is potentially not optimized as it might include debug functionality.

Comment: If I email him the apk from the directory Tim mentioned, and he uses it, and it eventually does crash, is there any way for him to see the stacktrace/error and tell me what it was?

Comment: Not unless he knows how to use ADB to catch stacktraces. You could integrate a debug report library like ACRA into your application. Then he can easily send you reports on a way configured by you (e.g. email).